# How to train your external oblique and serratus anterior?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, strength-training, bodyweight-exercises

What exercises are good to train the external oblique and serratus anterior muscles from beginner to advanced exercises?I am interested mostly in isolated exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExRx is your friend:

Obliques: http://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/WaistWt.html#Obliques

Serratus Anterior: http://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ChestWt.html#Anterior